# Method should have signature error. ¿What can i do?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I want to update a health bar in the server and clients, because the health value is updated on server, but not the bar. I tried everything, but dont managed to fix it

ERROR:

```
AlRecibirDaño should have signature: 
     public void AlRecibirDaño(System.Int32 oldValue, System.Int32 newValue) { }
  (at System.Void Health::AlRecibirDaño(System.Int32)) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) Mirror.Weaver.CompilationFinishedHook:HandleError(String) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/CompilationFinishedHook.cs:43) Mirror.Weaver.Log:Error(String) (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Program.cs:19) Mirror.Weaver.Weaver:Error(String, MemberReference) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Weaver.cs:155) Mirror.Weaver.SyncVarProcessor:GetHookMethod(TypeDefinition, FieldDefinition, String) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Processors/SyncVarProcessor.cs:44) Mirror.Weaver.SyncVarProcessor:GetHookMethod(TypeDefinition, FieldDefinition) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Processors/SyncVarProcessor.cs:26) Mirror.Weaver.SyncVarProcessor:ProcessSyncVarSet(TypeDefinition, FieldDefinition, String, Int64, FieldDefinition) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Processors/SyncVarProcessor.cs:199) Mirror.Weaver.SyncVarProcessor:ProcessSyncVar(TypeDefinition, FieldDefinition, Dictionary`2, Int64) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Processors/SyncVarProcessor.cs:265) Mirror.Weaver.SyncVarProcessor:ProcessSyncVars(TypeDefinition, List`1, List`1, Dictionary`2) (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Processors/SyncVarProcessor.cs:327) Mirror.Weaver.NetworkBehaviourProcessor:Process() 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Processors/NetworkBehaviourProcessor.cs:40) Mirror.Weaver.Weaver:ProcessNetworkBehaviourType(TypeDefinition) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Weaver.cs:201) Mirror.Weaver.Weaver:WeaveNetworkBehavior(TypeDefinition) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Weaver.cs:391) Mirror.Weaver.Weaver:WeaveModule(ModuleDefinition) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Weaver.cs:552) Mirror.Weaver.Weaver:Weave(String, IEnumerable`1, String, String, String) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Weaver.cs:488) Mirror.Weaver.Weaver:WeaveAssemblies(IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1, String, String, String) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Weaver.cs:582) Mirror.Weaver.Program:Process(String, String, String, String[], String[], Action`1, Action`1) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/Program.cs:33) Mirror.Weaver.CompilationFinishedHook:OnCompilationFinished(String, CompilerMessage[]) 
  (at Assets/Mirror/Editor/Weaver/CompilationFinishedHook.cs:147) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler()
```

CODE:

```
using UnityEngine; using Mirror;


public class Health : NetworkBehaviour {
    public RectTransform BarraVida;
    public const int VidaMax = 100;
    [SyncVar (hook = "AlRecibirDaño")] public int VidaActual = VidaMax;
    public void RecibirDaño(int Daño)
    {
        if (!isServer)
        {
            return;
        }
        VidaActual -= Daño;

        if (VidaActual <= 0)
        {
            VidaActual = 0;
            Debug.Log("Muerto");
        }
    }
    public void AlRecibirDaño(int vida)
    {
    BarraVida.sizeDelta = new Vector2(vida * 2, BarraVida.sizeDelta.y);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add second int to your method signature like `AlRecibirDaño(int vida, int vidaNew)`